# Cell linking to an external workbook shows #VALUE! error after saving and reopening when external workbook is not open

Tags: excel-2007

I'm using formula

```
=COUNTIFS('F:\kray_srrg\[ahw2.xlsx]kray_f2'!$A$2:$A$159451,B9,'F:\kray_srrg\[ahw2.xlsx]kray_f2'!$AC$2:$AC$159451,">64.5")
```

in an excel workbook list.xlsx and in this formula the file ahw2.xlsx is an external file. My problem is that when I close all files and again open list.xlsx then `#VALUE!` appears in place of result value. How can I keep the formula?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not lose the formula and it should show the same result as when list.xlsx was last saved if you choose to open list.xlsx without updating links. Since the formula is preserved, provided ahw2.xlsx has not been deleted or moved after list.xlsx was last saved you should be able to accept updating of links then go to Edit Links and Open Source to open ahw2.xlsx and automatically update `#VALUE!` to whatever is more appropriate at the time.